# Oracle : index on group by column?

Tags: oracle, indexing, group-by, query-optimization

I use Oracle and would like to optimize this query :

```
SELECT CDTYPE, SUM(MT1), SUM(MT2) 
FROM DETAILS
WHERE IDPARENT = 1234
AND CDSTATUT = 'O'
GROUP BY CDTYPE;
```

- IDPARENT is a FK, one IDPARENT could have 7 million rows with the same value
- MT1 and MT2 : NUMBER(15,2)
- CDSTATUT : VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), it can only have 2 different values
- CDTYPE : VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), it can have 30 different values

I tried to create an index on (IDPARENT, CDSTATUT, CDTYPE) but Oracle does not use it.
It use another index which is only on the IDPARENT column :
[screenshot execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxwtM.png)

What would be the best index to optimize this?

Comment: You mean IDPARENT has 7M different values? from your exec plan, it seems like it you have more than 6M rows with value 1234. If that is the case, an index will not help, and it would be better to do a full table scan.

Comment: Please clarify: there are 7 million distinct values of IDPARENT, or one IDPARENT could have 7 million rows with the same value?

Comment: Indeed sorry for the misunderstanding : one IDPARENT could have 7 million rows with the same value.